# Object id of nil false true in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the object id of nil, false, blank, true and Fixnums in ruby? 
How these object loaded in their priority .

Why it returns 4? I know that it's 4 but what is the logic behind the object id ?

Comment: just open your irb :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the object id of nil equal to 4? First, you need to know that false and true variables work exactly the same way as nil does. They are singleton instances of FalseClass and TrueClass, respectively. When the Ruby interpreter boots up, it initializes FalseClass, TrueClass and NilClass.

The result is:

> false.object_id
>   => 0
>
> true.object_id
>   => 2
>
> nil.object_id
>   => 4

What happened to 1 and 3? Well, the first bit is reserved for Fixnum values (numbers) only. Simple and consistent.

For getting the object ids of fixnum you may follow the formula:
object_id = (n*2)+1   [Where n is the fixnum]